# multiple insertion dynamic input fields using laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to insert multiple dynamic input fields into databse

So I have the following view :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").on("click", ".add_new_frm_field_btn", function() {

    var random = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000); //generate random values..
    var index = $(".form_field_outer").find(".form_field_outer_row").length + 1;

    $(".form_field_outer").append(
      `<div class="col-12 outer" data-index="${index}_${random}">
            <div class="card-body form_field_outer_row"> 
            <div class="form-row"><div class="form-group col-md-4">
             <label for="inputState">Casting</label>
            <select id="id_casting" class="form-control" name="id_casting[]">
                        <option selected>Choose...</option>
                        @foreach($castings as $casting)
                          <option data-id="{{$casting->id_casting}}" value="{{$casting->id_casting}}">{{$casting->nom.' '.$casting->prenom}}</option>
                          @endforeach
                     </select>
                     </div> 
        </div></div></div> `);
  })
  
  // Ajax for store data into databse
  
   $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          }
      });
         $('#submit').click(function(){ 

          $.ajax({  
                url:"{{route('ajout_projet.store')}}",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:$('#projetform').serialize(),
                type:'json',
           }); 

      }); 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<form method="POST" id="projetform" class="myForms" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <input type="hidden" id="id_projet" name="id_projet" />
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputAddress">Numéro de projet</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="numero_projet" name="numero_projet" placeholder="Description">
  </div>
  <div class="card mb-4 form_field_outer  ">
    <div class="card-body form_field_outer_row outer" data-index="0">
      <input type="hidden" id="id_projet_casting" name="id_projet_casting" />
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
          <label for="inputState">Casting</label>
          <select id="id_casting" class="form-control" name="id_casting[]">
            <option selected>Choose...</option>
            @foreach($castings as $casting)
            <option data-id="{{$casting->id_casting}}" value="{{$casting->id_casting}}">{{$casting->nom.' '.$casting->prenom}}</option>
            @endforeach
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary mb-1 add_new_frm_field_btn">Ajouter un nouveau casting</button>
<button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-1">Add</button>
```

And the following controller :

```
    $projets = Projet::create(array(
     'numero_projet' => $request['numero_projet']
));
    foreach($request->input('id_casting') as $key => $value) {
    
                          Projet_Casting::create([
                             'id_projet' =>  $projets->id,
                             'id_casting' => $request->input('id_casting')[$key],
                             'id_contrat'  => 1,
        ]);
    }
```

But this code stores only the value of only one input field and not all the added input fields, And the id_projet gets the null value, while it is a foreign key and should get the value of the inserted line in Projet Model.

If you have any idea help me

Comment: Hi, are you sure your ajax call execute ?

Comment: Hi , Yes I'm sure

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, I tested it and it saves the data to the database correctly. So  try to debug your controller and add success and error functions in the ajax call, i.e :

```
 $('#submit').click(function(){

          $.ajax({
                url:"{{route('questions.store')}}",
                method:"POST",
                data:$('#projetform').serialize(),
                type:'json',
                success: function(e){
                    console.log(e)
                },
                error: function(error){
                    console.log(error)
                }

           });

      });
```

And see what it produces in the browser console.

Comment: thank you for ur answer but it stills store only one input field and not multiple-input fields